# Using SSLContext with just a CA certificate and no keystore

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, ca, jersey-client

I need to setup a `javax.net.ssl.SSLContext` for use in a Jersey-Client application. All I want to do is the context to accept a custom root ca certificate. Is is really true that there is no way around of generating a keystore file and importing the CA certificate?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

> Is is really true that there is no way around of generating a keystore
>   file and importing the CA certificate?

There are way to do it without a keystore file, but since you would have to load the CA certificate you want to trust one way or another, you'll have to load a file or resource somehow.

(You could also certainly implement your own `TrustManager` that makes all the calls to use the Certification Path API, without using the `KeyStore` API at all, but that would only increase the complexity of your code, not reduce it. You would also need to understand the [*Java PKI Programmer's Guide*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/certpath/CertPathProgGuide.html) to do this correctly.)

If you really don't want a keystore file, you could use the `KeyStore` API in memory and load the certificate directly.

Something along these lines should work (not tested):

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("cacert.crt");
// You could get a resource as a stream instead.

CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
X509Certificate caCert = (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(is);

TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory
    .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
ks.load(null); // You don't need the KeyStore instance to come from a file.
ks.setCertificateEntry("caCert", caCert);

tmf.init(ks);

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
```

(Remember to close everything and handle the exceptions.)

Whether loading the certificate this way or loading the certificate into a similar `KeyStore` instance from a keystore file is more convenient is up to you to decide.

Comment: To anyone coming across this answer, be sure to use the import `javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory` and NOT `com.sun.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory`; the later is now deprecated. Cheers.

Comment: @MattClark Generally, you shouldn't import any `com.sun.*` or `sun.*` packages directly anyway.

Comment: In my case the certificate is added by the user (through settings) and arrives as a Base64 string: `java.io.InputStream is = new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream( java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(cert) );` works like a charm. Thanks!