# Java MySQL SSL/TLS certificate validation without using keystore and truststore

Tags: java, mysql, ssl, ssl-certificate

I use truststore and keystore files to connect to my MySQL Server with SSL and certificate validation:
[image]

I created the `truststore/keystore`  from this three files using this manual:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html

[image]

My Question is, if it is possible to do the certificate validation without a `truststore/keystore` but instead directely with the : `client-key.pem / ca-cert.pem / client-cert.pem`

The thing is that I want to keep my application simple and I know that the Database server will always give me the `.pem` files when we move to another database server. But then the user needs to create new `truststore/keystore` files, for me it would be nicer if I could only point to the path where the `.pem` files are located.

Comment: One solution is to implement your own `KeyStore` implementation that reads the `PEM` files directly.  Then, tell your application to use the custom keystore instead of the java provided file backed one.

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513792/using-sslcontext-with-just-a-ca-certificate-and-no-keystore/18514628#18514628.