# Check a certificate validity against a custom trust list in Java

Tags: java, security, x509certificate

I have a document that is digitally signed using CAdES. I use BouncyCastle APIs to get the `X509Certificate[]` instances of the signers, but let's assume the list contains one and one only element.

I need to verify whether this certificate is trusted or not at today's date, and I don't want to use the system's standard trust store which is normally used to trust SSL certificates. No, I want to build my own trust list with a list of `.cer` files in my classpath. At the moment, a single CA is trusted but obviously in the future a few more certificates may be added.

So far I have read *[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18514628/471213)* and tried to implement in my code. I need no `SSLContext`, I need to check the validity of a digitally signed document. I am now confused.

`X509TrustManager` APIs do however provide only methods for validating client/server certificates, but mine only have digital signature/non-repudiation usage flags.

The questions can be formulated in two ways that lead to the same:

1. How does one in Java check the validity of an `X509Certificate` instance against a custom root CA list that can be loaded in memory?
2. How does one check that a digitally-signed document is signed with a certificate deriving from a known CA of a custom list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract from the CAdES signature for each signer the signer's certificate and also the intermediate certificates as a `X509Certificate` list. Build also a set with all root CA certificates

Then you can use this (slightly adapted) [example code](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=cattle-master/code/iaas/ssh-common/src/main/java/io/cattle/platform/ssh/common/SslCertificateUtils.java) to verify and build the certification chain using Java and BouncyCastle. It will return the certification chain if verification is successful

```
public PKIXCertPathBuilderResult verifyCertificateChain(
     X509Certificate cert, 
     Set<X509Certificate> trustedRootCerts,
     Set<X509Certificate> intermediateCerts) throws GeneralSecurityException {

    // Create the selector that specifies the starting certificate
    X509CertSelector selector = new X509CertSelector(); 
    selector.setCertificate(cert);

    // Create the trust anchors (set of root CA certificates)
    Set<TrustAnchor> trustAnchors = new HashSet<TrustAnchor>();
    for (X509Certificate trustedRootCert : trustedRootCerts) {
        trustAnchors.add(new TrustAnchor(trustedRootCert, null));
    }

    // Configure the PKIX certificate builder algorithm parameters
    PKIXBuilderParameters pkixParams = 
        new PKIXBuilderParameters(trustAnchors, selector);

    // Disable CRL checks (this is done manually as additional step)
    pkixParams.setRevocationEnabled(false);

    // Specify a list of intermediate certificates
    // certificate itself has to be added to the list 
    intermediateCerts.add(cert); 
    CertStore intermediateCertStore = CertStore.getInstance("Collection",
        new CollectionCertStoreParameters(intermediateCerts), "BC");
    pkixParams.addCertStore(intermediateCertStore);

    // Build and verify the certification chain
    CertPathBuilder builder = CertPathBuilder.getInstance("PKIX", "BC");
    PKIXCertPathBuilderResult result = 
        (PKIXCertPathBuilderResult) builder.build(pkixParams);
    return result;
}
```

If you do not want to deal with CAdES complexity, I suggest to use [SD-DSS](https://github.com/esig/dss) open-source project

Comment: Luckily, BouncyCastle helped me a lot to deal with CAdES complexity by extracting the signer certificate and document hash code

Comment: Hmmm... no matter what, I always get an exception that "No certificate found matching targetConstraints". I tried to load the trustedRootCerts also from system trust store, which contains the target root CA (debugging, I found the correct certificate in the in-memory store)

Comment: The certificate itself has to be added to the intermediate list `intermediateCerts.add(cert);` The code i've linked is not correct. I have updated the link with the original source

Comment: Could you check the modified answer?

Comment: Will do in the following days. For the moment I have workarounded the whole thing by the luck of assuming that the path length IS always 1 (user cert is not signed by intermediate CA). I am behind schedule as the majority of developers :-(